# Exclude specific subdirectory with gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Let say there is directory structure like this:

```
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir_1        # do not want this
│   │   ├── file1.txt   # and this
│   │   └── file2.txt   # and this
│   ├── subdir_2        # keep me in gitignore
│   └── subdir_3        # keep me as well
└── dir2
    └── subdir4
        ├── file3.txt
        └── file4.txt
```

And I want to `gitignore` everything what is in the `dir1` directory but not want to include `subdir_1`.
Which means I want to track changes in `subdir_1` and not in `subdir_2 or subdir_3`

How to do this ?

I already tried

```
/dir1/
!/dir/subdir_1
```

In fact my `.gitignore` file is much more longer and I was googling for solutions for that problem. They told me to first ignore everything with `*` and then negate it. But I'd prefer a more simple solution and not to refactor the existing `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have files in subdir_1  *not* ignored, try this:

```
dir1/*
!dir1/subdir_1*
!dir1/subdir_1/*
```

EDIT: tested on your specific structure :)

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitignore
        new file:   dir1/subdir_1/good_file1.txt
        new file:   dir1/subdir_1/good_file2.txt
        new file:   dir2/subdir4/file3.txt
        new file:   dir2/subdir4/file4.txt
```

Comment: hmm.. I am sorry, but even updated question does not help me understand what you really want. What does "keep me in gitignore" mean then? Does it mean that you want everything inside dir1 to be tracked,  _except_ subdir_1 folder?

Comment: @jmod999 and what the point in deleting your comments? So it looks like I am talking to myself now...